# How to handle passing data around internally within the app, in an PHP application?

Tags: php, oop, data-structures, architecture, system

So if I need to pass data around the application internally is there nice predictable way to pass it around.

I want to be able to look at a function and know whats in the collection that is getting passed into the function.

An array is an unpredictable data structure, so you never know what you're getting.

I feel like it's better to have an object defined with named properties and pass that around the application instead of an array, because that way theres SOME sort of a definition available.

The issue with that is that there will just be an bunch of objects accumulating in some folder somewhere.

Was wondering anyone's opinion on this, and any other alternatives?

Comment: _"an bunch of objects accumulating in some folder somewhere"_ - Are you storing them as files? How you should pass them around depends on your application, which we know nothing about. In general, I prefer passing around objects (called Value objects) over arrays, since you then can define what properties should be available.

Comment: This has to be the vaguest question I've ever read. Please provide some actual context.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. That's exactly what I was looking for. Value Objects. So where do you keep these?  Any reccomendations for best practices on how to use them?

Comment: _"where to keep these"_ - It totally depends on your application structure. You can keep them where ever you want. Regarding _"how to use them"_, they are objects, use them as such...

Comment: @jonrsharpe   You're correct, it's vague. An example would be, if I have a function with a single parameter that is an array the function looks like this:public function ($some_array){}There's no predictable way to know what's in that array. But if do:public function (CustomObject $some_object){}I can look at that object file and know what's being passed into my function.Thats what Magnus is calling a Value Object.  However,  I feel like there could be an accumulation of a bunch of value objects in a folder because every different piece of functionality could require a new value object.

Comment: IMO, you are worrying about something that doesn't end up being a real issue. I have a substantial system and I use arrays exclusively for moving data around. So long as the array has what I need, then all is well. I check for existence of what I require and throw an exception if it isn't there. I trust that the data my function receives is correct because I'm the one calling it. In 3 years we have never had some random data getting sent to our functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having a larger (although - hidden) problem. A structure in your code should not cross more than one layer boundary.

If some structure  (doesn't matter whether it is an array or an object) is crossing two layers, then, unless it is an intentional compromise, it is a sign, that there might be "architectural flaws" indicating fragility of your codebase. Such cross-cutting data structures become the fault-lines across witch your codebase exhibits none-trivial bugs.

If your have structures, that cross 3 or more layer boundaries, your codebase is fucked. It becomes one of those *"kill it with fire, before it lays eggs"* projects.

The solution that I use is this:

Instead of having dedicated "data structures" being passed around, focus your business logic around [domain objects](http://wiki.c2.com/?DomainObject). You create it at some point in the layer, where you will be actually using it logic-related behaviour and inject it or return it to other layer only to affect it.

Kinda like this:

```
public function loginWithPassword(Entity\EmailIdentity $identity, string $password): Entity\CookieIdentity
{
    if ($identity->matchPassword($password) === false) {
        throw new PasswordMismatch;
    }
    $identity->setPassword($password);
    $this->updateEmailIdentityOnUse($identity);
    $cookie = $this->createCookieIdentity($identity);

    return $cookie;
}
```

What is being passed in an out of this method is not some "data structure", but a fully formed logical entity, which contains specific, business-relate behaviour.

Comment: Awesome.  I like this a lot. Instead of some 'abstract' data structure pass around more focused domain specific objects.

Comment: If you can, yes. The problem will be that actually figuring out a good structure for your domain (and creating the accompanying class) is quite hard first few times.